# removing variables in global environment before exiting a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

For a Shiny app that I am making, I have to define some variables in the global environment as they need to be available to many functions here and there. Some of these variables don't exist to start with and are created as the user interacts with the app. The app is to check for existence of the variables and if they don't exist, it has to do something. However, after one session of use, the variables come into existence and stay in the global environment. When the user starts the app again, the app sees the variables in the global environment and so it behaves the way it is not supposed to behave. Is there a way I can remove the variables I create just before the user chooses to terminate the app? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The valid way to solution that would be using [`onStop`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/onStop.html) function as in:

```
onStop(function() cat("Session stopped\n"))
```

The [linked documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/onStop.html) suggests using that within `server` function.

Answer (score -1):

Create a function to cleanup when exiting using `on.exit`.  `on.exit` records the expression given as its argument as needing to be executed when the current function exits (either naturally or as the result of an error). This is useful for resetting graphical parameters or performing other cleanup actions.

```
on.exit(rm(list= list(myListOfThings)))
```

Comment: This is not correct. Placing `on.exit` within a `server` call immediately exists the app. The answer should provide an example of how this should be done as shiny offers `onStop` designed for that purpose.